# Is it mandatory jre/jdk required to install installer created from install4j? if yes then is it possible to reduce size upto 10mb

Tags: install4j

Is it mandatory jre/jdk required to install installer created from install4j?  if yes then it is possible to reduce jre size less than 10mb?

Actually, I want to use install4j for the installer and packager for my product but product is in golang so that will not require JRE but only for install4j I need to bundle JRE so it's adding about 45-50mb size to my package. is it reducible up to 10mb(total size of only jre <= 10mb) so I can go ahead with install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory to bundle a JRE, install4j can detect installed JREs. However, it is recommended to bundle a JRE to ensure that the installer and the launchers will work.

The smallest JRE bundles can be obtained with a Java 11 JRE, setting the module set to "Minimum" on the "General Settings->JRE bundles step".

Comment: Using 1st comment my doubt is cleared we need JRE on the machine where we want to install the installer created from install4j. correct me if I am missing something.

using 2nd comment I have tried with the minimum module set and it's working now my jre size is around 30MB . Is it any way to reduce that size more (around 10MB)?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: should I try to reduce size with jlink once or install4j already using jlink ?